# dynamic textsize change in ice cream sandawich

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to change text size when button is clicked.
xml :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:text="hello_world"

   android:textSize="30sp"
   android:layout_margin=""/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="72dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button1" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView1"
    android:text="Button2" />
```

This is my code :

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    txtmain=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    txtmain.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP ,30);

    //txtmain.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP ,30);

    txtmain.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), 12);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn2=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    txtmain.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
    btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtmain=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);


            txtmain.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP ,30);
            System.out.println("txtmain get height:"+txtmain.getHeight());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"txtmain get 
            //height:"+txtmain.getHeight() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });

    btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            txtmain=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            txtmain.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP ,80);
            System.out.println("txtmain get height:"+txtmain.getHeight());
            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"txtmain get 
             //height:"+txtmain.getHeight() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

When I click button 1, it gives proper output but when I click button 2 after clicking button1 output changes.

Here is my output :

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you post the layout xml please? That may provide some idea about what is going on. Thanks!

Comment: @NeilTownsend : i am put xml file .

Comment: @AlexanderW , i am edit my code please see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would appear to be quite similar to known a known issue on ICS, see https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=22493 and https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17343. The second of these suggests that a workaround is to add a "\n" to the text in the text view. Reading up those pages and those they link to may help resolve the issue for you.

Comment: thank you ,i solve my problem .append text in textview final String DOUBLE_BYTE_WORDJOINER = "\u2060";

Answer (score 1):

The problem is

```
 txtmain.setHeight(41);
```

in first button click, So it will change the height of the textview from `WRAP CONTENT`  to a fixed size. Just remove it..

Comment: text box height is my testing line ,i am remove it.still problem is occure .is there any solution.

Comment: running my code in all os perfect but in ice cream sandwich .different output .

Answer (score 0):

Why are you setting the text box height wen you click the button1?

Comment: text box height is my testing line ,i am remove it.